# Pandas datetime find the nearest date before a given date. If it doesn't exist, get the nearest date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have different groups of transactions, and within each transaction group there are different dates. I want to get the nearest date that is *before* a given date. *However*, if it doesn't exist, just get the nearest date. For example,

Say the given date for the following two examples is:
`np.datetime(2014,12,16)`

**Example 1**:

The dates within the group are: `np.datetime(2014,12,17)`, `np.datetime(2014,12,15)`, and `np.datetime(2014,12,14)`

The returned value should be `np.datetime(2014,12,15)` since it the nearest date BEFORE the given date from above. We prioritize not only getting a date that is *before* the given date, but also the *closest* one to it.

**Example 2**:

The dates within the group are: `np.datetime(2014,12,17)`, `np.datetime(2014,12,18)`, and `np.datetime(2014,12,19)`

The returned value should be `np.datetime(2014,12,17)` since there are no dates before the given date, the nearest date to the above date will be turned.

I found a function that looks like it can satisfy the 2nd example, but not the first:

`def nearest(items, pivot):
    return min(items, key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `searchsorted`

```
def yourfunc(items,pivot):
    items=np.sort(items)
    if np.searchsorted(items,s)==0:
        return items[np.searchsorted(items,s)]
    else :
        return items[np.searchsorted(items, s)-1]

yourfunc(ary1,s)
Out[148]: datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 15, 0, 0)
yourfunc(ary2,s)
Out[149]: datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 17, 0, 0)
```

Data input

```
ary1=np.array([pd.datetime(2014,12,17), pd.datetime(2014,12,15), pd.datetime(2014,12,14)])
ary2=np.array([pd.datetime(2014,12,17), pd.datetime(2014,12,18), pd.datetime(2014,12,19)]


s=pd.datetime(2014,12,16)
```